# How to get an access to sprite in 2d array?

Tags: python, sprite

I want to replace array string 'a' with sprite, thus I display images :

```
arr = ['a','a','a','a']
for i in arr:
    if i == 'p':
        arr[i] = Alien("Alien.png", (20,40))
print(arr[1])                  
# give  <Alien sprite(in 0 groups)>
```

Next I tried to figure out how to get access to each image to give a motion for every image after replace in array, but code doesn't work as I expected. I don't know how to operate each image apart?

```
for j in arr:
    if j == '<Alien sprite(in 0 groups)>':
        j.move(9,11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second loop, I don't think `j == ..` would work in you favour. When you print the object in the python prompt it would print `<PawnBlue sprite(in 0 groups)>`, however checking the string equality as you have wouldn't be right way to check if that particular array index contains an image or not.

I see in your previous loop you are inserting instances of the `Alien` class into the array. Assuming those are the images that you are talking about, in the second loop change the if statement to `if type(j) == Alien :`  This should work.